# typedef of enum bool return error in the compilation

Tags: c

I want to define bool type (enum format)

```
typedef enum bool_enum {
    false, 
    true,
} bool;
```

But is returning the folowing error in the compilation

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
  false, 
error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘_Bool’
 } bool;
```

What is wrong in the enum type definition?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have `<stdbool.h>` included, which typically contains:

```
#define true   1
#define false  0
```

So your names are not good, they collide with standard headers (which of course also define the name `bool` itself).

Drop this, and just use `<stdbool.h>` would be my advice.

Comment: Also the name of the enum `bool` clashes with the `stdbool.h` typedef. In fact, that is what is causing the second error.

Comment: @JeremyP True, I added that. Thanks.